# Observing changes to ES6 Maps and Sets

Tags: dictionary, set, ecmascript-6

Is there any way to observe additions to and removals from ES6 Maps and Sets? [Object.observe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) doesn't work because it is only applies to direct properties of the observed object. Hypothetically the `size` property could be observed, but no indication would be provided of exactly what has changed. Another idea would be to replace the object's `set` and `get` functions with proxified versions. Is there a better way? If not, I'm surprised that nobody thought of this when the proposals were being written for ES6.

Comment: Proxying is pretty much your only option.

Comment: Subclass them and overwrite `set`/`get`, yeah.

Comment: @user5321531: *"Object.observe doesn't work because it is only applies to direct properties of the observed object"*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this with a vanilla Map/Set. In general observation of object properties alone is controversial (that is why `Object.observe` is only a proposal, and not an accepted part of the spec). Observing private state, like the internals of a Map or Set (or Date or Promise, for that matter), is definitely not on the table.

Note also that since `size` is a getter, not a data property, `Object.observe` will not notify you of changes to it.

As you mention, you can achieve such "observation" via collaboration between the mutator and the observer. You could either do this with a normal Map/Set plus a side-channel (e.g. a function returning a `{ Map, EventEmitter }` object), or via a subclass tailored for the purpose, or a specific instance created for that purpose.

Comment: This is why Proxy should support Map and Set, not just Objects and Functions

Answer (score 2):

Subclassing for `Set/Map` is not working at the moment. How about this method (just hasty example)?

```
//ECMAScript 2015
class XMap
{
  constructor(iterable, observer = null)
  {
    this._map      = new Map(iterable);
    this._observer = observer;
    this._changes  = {};
  }
  set(key, value)
  {
    this._changes.prev = this._map.get(key);
    this._changes.new  = value;
    this._map.set(key, value);

    if(this._observer !== null)
    {
      this._observer(this._changes);
    }
  }
  get(key)
  {
    return this._map.get(key); 
  }
}

var m = new XMap([[0, 1]], changes => console.log(changes));

m.set(0,5);  // console: Object {prev: 1, new: 5}
m.set(0,15); // console: Object {prev: 5, new: 15}
```