# How to use Object.observe on Map?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6, object.observe

How to use [Object.observe](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) on Map?
This doesn't work:

```
var map = new Map();
Object.observe(map, function() { console.log("ok"); });
map.set('key', 'value');
```

And this too:

```
var map = new Map();
Array.observe(map, function() { console.log("ok"); });
map.set('key', 'value');
```

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [Observing changes to ES6 Maps and Sets](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29909823/218196)

Answer (score 4):

The `Object.observe()` facility is a general way to watch for changes to an object. Calls to the `Map` API do not trigger any of the events that the `.observe()` facility watches for, because no properties of the `Map` object are added, remove, changed, etc.

Current ES6/ES2015 specs make no provisions for observing updates to `Map` or `Set` instances, as far as I can tell.